# How to find the type of derived class without multiple "is" statements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I find a bunch of questions close to this, but not quite answering it, though I'm sure it's on here somewhere.

I'm looking to simply find which derived class I'm dealing with from a base class reference.

I have blocks of code like this

```
    public void AddMenu(iTarget target, Menu callingMenu)
{
    if (target is Corporation)
        AddMenu(target as Corporation, callingMenu);
    if (target is Company)
        AddMenu(target as Company, callingMenu);
    if (target is Asset)
        AddMenu(target as Asset, callingMenu);
    if (target is Operative)
        AddMenu(target as Operative, callingMenu);
}
```

And

```
if (uip.UIPButton is UIPCorporationButton)
        btn = UIPCorporationButton.Create(contents.gameObject, (uip as Corporation));
else if (uip.UIPButton is UIPCompanyButton)
        btn = UIPCompanyButton.Create(contents.gameObject, (uip as Company));
else if (uip.UIPButton is UIPAssetButton)
        btn = UIPAssetButton.Create(contents.gameObject, (uip as Asset));
else if (uip.UIPButton is UIPIndButton)
//so on and so on
```

And I'd like to use something like this:

```
public void AddMenu(iTarget target, Menu callingMenu)
{
    AddMenu(BaseClass(target));//or whatever would send iTarget as Corporation, Company, or whatever it's base type is
}
```

Or something like:

```
public void DoThing(iTarget target)
{
    switch(target.BaseClass)//or whatever
    {
        case Corporation:
            //stuff
            break;
        case Company:
            //other stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to just get the derived class and use it as a reference like above?

Comment: You're looking for the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetType() with an if/else statement will do what you want.

```
    private abstract class Base1
    {

    }

    private class Extend1 : Base1
    {

    }

        Base1 whatTypeAmI = new Extend1();
        var t = whatTypeAmI.GetType();

        if (t == typeof(Extend1))
            {
                //do work
                Console.WriteLine("hello extend1");
            }
        else {
                Console.WriteLine("I don't know what type I am");
            }
        }
```

Comment: So this should have better performance against the constant casting, right? since it only finds what type once and then just checks the class type?

Comment: Yes, the performance will be good because it's only doing GetType() once.

That being said, you should look at PMF's response below to see if you could use an ITarget.  If it applies to your particular scenario it is a good suggestion.

Comment: the problem is I need to figure out what iTarget is at *some* point, as it determines what menu to call up, and what data to show. iTarget is a very broad interface in this with most "things" in the game world having it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you really need that switch statement first. I don't know how your `AddMenu` works exactly, but if it takes an `ITarget`, why do you need the cast at all? Just call it with the base class.

Often, if this "switch on a type" construct is seemingly required, there is a design flaw. A virtual method call is the ordinary way to do this, so consider refactoring your code so you can do

```
target.AddMenu(callingMenu);
```

instead.

Comment: well the target is a game class so it shouldnt have gui logic like a method on it. That addmenu is taking in some target, and casting it bewcause there is a separate row of AddMenu(Corporation corp, Menu callingmenu) and etc. methods, that call up the specific menu associated with that class (in this example, it calls the CorpMenu and sends the corp to that menu to populate the information). so when the iTarget's button is clicked, it pulls whatever iTarget is on the button, sends it to this, figures out what menu it should call, and sends the class the menu should show.

Comment: Ok, then I agree that the Ui should not be mixed into the logic. You could then use an interface or an event between your game class and the Ui with a factory that returns the right AddMenu method.

Comment: +1 to this.  @LZG You shouldn't **ever** need a switch-statement on the type, that's what virtual methods are for in the first place.